# Export to excel issue in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel

Im using this code for export table data to excel. I have been trying this it just displaying the data on the screen, do i need to do any modification. Im not able to see the file, dont even have any idea whether it is exporting to file or not. I guess it is not doing any thing rather than displaying data on the screen.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM myrecords";
$qr = mysql_query( $q ) or die( mysql_error() );


// Ok now we are going to send some headers so that this
// thing that we are going make comes out of browser
// as an xls file.
//
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");

//this line is important its makes the file name
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export_file.xls ");

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

// start the file
xlsBOF();

// these will be used for keeping things in order.
$col = 0;
$row = 0;

// This tells us that we are on the first row
$first = true;

while( $qrow = mysql_fetch_assoc( $qr ) )
{
// Ok we are on the first row
// lets make some headers of sorts
if( $first )
{
foreach( $qrow as $k => $v )
{
// take the key and make label
// make it uppper case and replace _ with ' '
xlsWriteLabel( $row, $col, strtoupper( ereg_replace( "_" , " " , $k ) ) );
$col++;
}

// prepare for the first real data row
$col = 0;
$row++;
$first = false;
}

// go through the data
foreach( $qrow as $k => $v )
{
// write it out
xlsWriteLabel( $row, $col, $v );
$col++;
}
// reset col and goto next row
$col = 0;
$row++;
}

xlsEOF();
exit();
```

Please suggest any modification required?

Comment: You realise that you can only have one Content-Type header, so using three is totally meaningless

Comment: actually i have taken this from an article. everyone in the comments saying that it is working fine. But it is not working for me... @markBaker

Comment: Sorry, clearly all those people know vastly more about internet protocols like http and about Excel than me, I'll consider myself suitably chastened and go and stand on the naughty step for daring to correct such experts